# Why is logo in navbar not aligned with text in container in CSS (Bootstrap)?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have problem with alignment of my logo in my navbar in Bootstrap.
I would like to align it with my website content, but it keeps shifting to the left. Any idea why this happens and how I can solve this? I was not able to find the solution.

**HTML:**

```
  <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">
                    <img alt="logo" height="13" width="100" src="{% static 'images/logo1.png' %}">
                </a>
            </div>
            <div id="navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
                <p class="navbar-text project-title">Part Activity</p>
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li><a href="about">About</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
```

**CSS:**

```
body {
    padding-top: 50px;
}

.navbar-brand {
    padding: 18px 0;
}

.project-title {
    color: #cc0000 !important;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.active-row {
    background-color: #C6EFCE;
}
```

**PROBLEM:**[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
         Use: col-sm-1 in <div class="navbar-hearder col-sm-1">
    If you increase the width
 of the image, you also need to increase: 
    col-sm-2..
     <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="navbar-header col-sm-1">
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">
                        <img alt="logo" height="13" width="100" src="{% static 'images/logo1.png' %}">
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div id="navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
                    <p class="navbar-text project-title">Part Activity</p>
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li><a href="about">About</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
    <div class="container">
        <h3>Part Activity</h3>
        <p>Master rsl</p>
    </div>
```

Comment: Thank you! This solved it. There is a small typ0 in the first line "navbar-hearder" should be "navbar-header".

Comment: .col-sm-1 {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 1px;
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-left: 15px;
}